# Suggestions for free flash decompilier?

Tags: flash, decompiler, swf-decompiler

I am editing a video player wrapper and need to change a color in the flash but don't have the FLV file. Does anyone have a suggestion for a good free flash decompiler? I need one to edit more than just the action script. Thanks.

Comment: do you mean the FLA file, not the FLV? (FLV would be the video you're playing while the FLA would most likely be the player you're pulling the video into)

Answer (score 0):

Try it [HP SWFScan](http://www.brothersoft.com/hp-swfscan-253747.html)

Enjoy,

Cleber.

Comment: Thanks. I should've have put that I didn't have the flv. The original post is corrected. I do have flash cs4